# How to centrally-orient a single showwaves (or showfreqs) overlay against two symmetrically-scrolling showspectrum overlays with ffmpeg?

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, command-line-interface

I'm trying to correctly `map` and centrally-orient a single `showwaves` (or `showfreqs`) overlay against two symmetrically-scrolling `showspectrum` overlays with ffmpeg, e.g.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=1:slide=scroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080,pad=1920:1080[vs]; [0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=rscroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080[ss]; [0:a]showwaves=s=960x540:mode=p2p[sw]; [vs][ss]overlay=w[out]; [out][sw]overlay=w[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv
```

[image]

As shown in the screen capture above, the `showwaves` overlay is stubbornly fixed in the upper right quadrant. The intent is to have it display horizontally across the center.

Bonus points if you can help me thicken the lines drawn by the `showwaves` filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -i input.mp3 -filter_complex "[0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=1:slide=scroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080,pad=1920:1080[vs]; [0:a]showspectrum=color=fiery:saturation=2:slide=rscroll:scale=log:win_func=gauss:overlap=1:s=960x1080[ss]; [0:a]showwaves=s=1920x540:mode=p2p,inflate[sw]; [vs][ss]overlay=w[out]; [out][sw]overlay=0:(H-h)/2[out]" -map "[out]" -map 0:a -c:v libx264 -preset fast -crf 18 -c:a copy output.mkv`

Co-ordinates set for the overlay of showwaves. showwaves size also changed to span full width. Added inflate filter to simulate "thickness" but in terms of quality, YMMV.

Comment: Works as intended, thank you. Any tips to improve quality, now that you mention it?